# Where is struct lws_context defined?

Tags: libwebsockets

I am new to libwebsocket and I have code to analyse. I could not find where is struct lws_context defined.
Can any one help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching through the /usr/include folder for the definition of lws_context you won't find it (I also did a quick search on their public doxygen and didn't find a definition there either...). However you can find its definition in their git repo (link on their site here: https://libwebsockets.org/). It is in the following file: lib/core/private-lib-core.h. It is worth mentioning that this is obviously subject to change in the future. For quick reference here is the definition you are looking for:

```cpp
struct lws_context {
 #if defined(LWS_WITH_SERVER)
        char canonical_hostname[96];
 #endif

#if defined(LWS_WITH_FILE_OPS)
        struct lws_plat_file_ops fops_platform;
#endif

#if defined(LWS_WITH_ZIP_FOPS)
        struct lws_plat_file_ops fops_zip;
#endif

        lws_system_blob_t system_blobs[LWS_SYSBLOB_TYPE_COUNT];

#if defined(LWS_WITH_SYS_SMD)
        lws_smd_t                               smd;
#endif
#if defined(LWS_WITH_SECURE_STREAMS)
        struct lws_ss_handle                    *ss_cpd;
#endif
        lws_sorted_usec_list_t                  sul_cpd_defer;

#if defined(LWS_WITH_NETWORK)
        struct lws_context_per_thread           pt[LWS_MAX_SMP];
        lws_retry_bo_t                          default_retry;
        lws_sorted_usec_list_t                  sul_system_state;

        lws_lifecycle_group_t                   lcg[LWSLCG_COUNT];

#if defined(LWS_WITH_NETLINK)
        lws_sorted_usec_list_t                  sul_nl_coldplug;
#endif

#if defined(LWS_PLAT_FREERTOS) || defined(WIN32)
        struct sockaddr_in                      frt_pipe_si;
#endif

#if defined(LWS_WITH_HTTP2)
        struct http2_settings                   set;
#endif

#if LWS_MAX_SMP > 1
        struct lws_mutex_refcount               mr;
#endif

#if defined(LWS_WITH_SYS_METRICS)
        lws_dll2_owner_t                        owner_mtr_dynpol;
        /**< owner for lws_metric_policy_dyn_t (dynamic part of metric pols) */
        lws_dll2_owner_t                        owner_mtr_no_pol;
        /**< owner for lws_metric_pub_t with no policy to bind to */
#endif

#if defined(LWS_WITH_NETWORK)
/*
 * LWS_WITH_NETWORK =====>
 */

        lws_dll2_owner_t                owner_vh_being_destroyed;

        lws_metric_t                    *mt_service; /* doing service */
        const lws_metric_policy_t       *metrics_policies;
        const char                      *metrics_prefix;

#if defined(LWS_WITH_SYS_METRICS) && defined(LWS_WITH_CLIENT)
        lws_metric_t                    *mt_conn_tcp; /* client tcp conns */
        lws_metric_t                    *mt_conn_tls; /* client tcp conns */
        lws_metric_t                    *mt_conn_dns; /* client dns external lookups */
        lws_metric_t                    *mth_conn_failures; /* histogram of conn failure reasons */
#if defined(LWS_ROLE_H1) || defined(LWS_ROLE_H2)
        lws_metric_t                    *mt_http_txn; /* client http transaction */
#endif
#if defined(LWS_WITH_SYS_ASYNC_DNS)
        lws_metric_t                    *mt_adns_cache; /* async dns lookup lat */
#endif
#if defined(LWS_WITH_SECURE_STREAMS)
        lws_metric_t                    *mt_ss_conn; /* SS connection latency */
#endif
#if defined(LWS_WITH_SECURE_STREAMS_PROXY_API)
        lws_metric_t                    *mt_ss_cliprox_conn; /* SS cli->prox conn */
        lws_metric_t                    *mt_ss_cliprox_paylat; /* cli->prox payload latency */
        lws_metric_t                    *mt_ss_proxcli_paylat; /* prox->cli payload latency */
#endif
#endif /* client */

#if defined(LWS_WITH_SERVER)
        lws_metric_t                    *mth_srv;
#endif

#if defined(LWS_WITH_EVENT_LIBS)
        struct lws_plugin               *evlib_plugin_list;
        void                            *evlib_ctx; /* overallocated */
#endif

#if defined(LWS_WITH_TLS)
        struct lws_context_tls          tls;
#endif
#if defined(LWS_WITH_DRIVERS)
        lws_netdevs_t                   netdevs;
#endif

#if defined(LWS_WITH_SYS_ASYNC_DNS)
        lws_async_dns_t                 async_dns;
#endif

#if defined(LWS_WITH_SYS_NTPCLIENT)
        void                            *ntpclient_priv;
#endif

#if defined(LWS_WITH_SECURE_STREAMS)
        struct lws_ss_handle            *hss_fetch_policy;
#if defined(LWS_WITH_SECURE_STREAMS_SYS_AUTH_API_AMAZON_COM)
        struct lws_ss_handle            *hss_auth;
        lws_sorted_usec_list_t          sul_api_amazon_com;
        lws_sorted_usec_list_t          sul_api_amazon_com_kick;
#endif
#if !defined(LWS_WITH_SECURE_STREAMS_STATIC_POLICY_ONLY)
        struct lws_ss_x509              *server_der_list;
#endif
#endif

#if defined(LWS_WITH_SYS_STATE)
        lws_state_manager_t             mgr_system;
        lws_state_notify_link_t         protocols_notify;
#endif
#if defined (LWS_WITH_SYS_DHCP_CLIENT)
        lws_dll2_owner_t                dhcpc_owner;
                                        /**< list of ifaces with dhcpc */
#endif

        /* pointers */

        struct lws_vhost                *vhost_list;
        struct lws_vhost                *no_listener_vhost_list;
        struct lws_vhost                *vhost_pending_destruction_list;
        struct lws_vhost                *vhost_system;

#if defined(LWS_WITH_SERVER)
        const char                      *server_string;
#endif

        const struct lws_event_loop_ops *event_loop_ops;
#endif

#if defined(LWS_WITH_TLS)
        const struct lws_tls_ops        *tls_ops;
#endif

#if defined(LWS_WITH_PLUGINS)
        struct lws_plugin               *plugin_list;
#endif
#ifdef _WIN32
/* different implementation between unix and windows */
        struct lws_fd_hashtable fd_hashtable[FD_HASHTABLE_MODULUS];
#else
        struct lws **lws_lookup;

#endif

/*
 * <====== LWS_WITH_NETWORK end
 */

#endif /* NETWORK */

#if defined(LWS_WITH_SECURE_STREAMS_PROXY_API)
        const char      *ss_proxy_bind;
        const char      *ss_proxy_address;
#endif

#if defined(LWS_WITH_FILE_OPS)
        const struct lws_plat_file_ops *fops;
#endif

        struct lws_context **pcontext_finalize;
#if !defined(LWS_PLAT_FREERTOS)
        const char *username, *groupname;
#endif

#if defined(LWS_AMAZON_RTOS) && defined(LWS_WITH_MBEDTLS)
        mbedtls_entropy_context mec;
        mbedtls_ctr_drbg_context mcdc;
#endif

#if defined(LWS_WITH_THREADPOOL)
        struct lws_threadpool *tp_list_head;
#endif

#if defined(LWS_WITH_PEER_LIMITS)
        struct lws_peer                 **pl_hash_table;
        struct lws_peer                 *peer_wait_list;
        lws_peer_limits_notify_t        pl_notify_cb;
        time_t                          next_cull;
#endif

        const lws_system_ops_t          *system_ops;

#if defined(LWS_WITH_SECURE_STREAMS)
#if !defined(LWS_WITH_SECURE_STREAMS_STATIC_POLICY_ONLY)
        const char                      *pss_policies_json;
        struct lwsac                    *ac_policy;
        void                            *pol_args;
#endif
        const lws_ss_policy_t           *pss_policies;
        const lws_ss_auth_t             *pss_auths;
#if defined(LWS_WITH_SSPLUGINS)
        const lws_ss_plugin_t           **pss_plugins;
#endif
#endif

        void *external_baggage_free_on_destroy;
        const struct lws_token_limits *token_limits;
        void *user_space;
#if defined(LWS_WITH_SERVER)
        const struct lws_protocol_vhost_options *reject_service_keywords;
        lws_reload_func deprecation_cb;
#endif
#if !defined(LWS_PLAT_FREERTOS)
        void (*eventlib_signal_cb)(void *event_lib_handle, int signum);
#endif

#if defined(LWS_HAVE_SYS_CAPABILITY_H) && defined(LWS_HAVE_LIBCAP)
        cap_value_t caps[4];
        char count_caps;
#endif

        lws_usec_t time_up; /* monotonic */

        uint64_t options;

        time_t last_ws_ping_pong_check_s;
#if defined(LWS_WITH_SECURE_STREAMS)
        time_t                                  last_policy;
#endif

#if defined(LWS_PLAT_FREERTOS)
        unsigned long time_last_state_dump;
        uint32_t last_free_heap;
#endif

        unsigned int max_fds;
#if !defined(LWS_NO_DAEMONIZE)
        pid_t started_with_parent;
#endif

#if !defined(LWS_PLAT_FREERTOS)
        uid_t uid;
        gid_t gid;
        int fd_random;
        int count_cgi_spawned;
#endif

        unsigned int fd_limit_per_thread;
        unsigned int timeout_secs;
        unsigned int pt_serv_buf_size;
        unsigned int max_http_header_data;
        unsigned int max_http_header_pool;
        int simultaneous_ssl_restriction;
        int simultaneous_ssl;
#if defined(LWS_WITH_PEER_LIMITS)
        uint32_t pl_hash_elements;      /* protected by context->lock */
        uint32_t count_peers;           /* protected by context->lock */
        unsigned short ip_limit_ah;
        unsigned short ip_limit_wsi;
#endif
        unsigned int deprecated:1;
        unsigned int inside_context_destroy:1;
        unsigned int being_destroyed:1;
        unsigned int service_no_longer_possible:1;
        unsigned int being_destroyed2:1;
        unsigned int requested_stop_internal_loops:1;
        unsigned int protocol_init_done:1;
        unsigned int doing_protocol_init:1;
        unsigned int done_protocol_destroy_cb:1;
        unsigned int evlib_finalize_destroy_after_int_loops_stop:1;
        unsigned int max_fds_unrelated_to_ulimit:1;
        unsigned int policy_updated:1;
#if defined(LWS_WITH_NETLINK)
        unsigned int nl_initial_done:1;
#endif

        unsigned short count_threads;
        unsigned short undestroyed_threads;
        short plugin_protocol_count;
        short plugin_extension_count;
        short server_string_len;
        unsigned short deprecation_pending_listen_close_count;
#if defined(LWS_WITH_SECURE_STREAMS_PROXY_API)
        uint16_t        ss_proxy_port;
#endif
        /* 0 if not known, else us resolution of the poll wait */
        uint16_t us_wait_resolution;

        uint8_t max_fi;
        uint8_t udp_loss_sim_tx_pc;
        uint8_t udp_loss_sim_rx_pc;
        uint8_t captive_portal_detect;
        uint8_t captive_portal_detect_type;

        uint8_t         destroy_state; /* enum lws_context_destroy */
};
```